# Geoserver of GeoTifs

Tags: geoserver

We have a series of geotif files covering a specific area of land.  If all tiffs are viewed at once they cover a large area and there are no gaps between them.  If I register each file as layer in geoserver and then create a layer group then the map produced looks great an all works OK.  However, the problem I have is that I have now been supplied with 500 tiff files which are to be registered and rendered in the same way.  Is there any way to register a set of tiffs rather than having to go through and register each one?

Comment: You can try, gdalbuildvrt myvrt.vrt dir/*.tif. Note that for .vrt, assuming all your tiff have similar characteristics : number of bands, projection, color interpretation, resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ImageMosaic store to create a layer based on multiple tifs. Just enter the directory containing your collection of source tifs in the url parameter and geoserver will create a layer based on all tifs for you.

See the [geoserver documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html#tutorial-imagemosaic-extension) for more information.